# How Do I Bind Two HTML Elements to the same object in ASP MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

This is a simple question, but I am new to MVC and ASP.NET, so more explanation is better on this one. I have a Portfolio class that has a list of industries associated with it. The classes (simplified) are below:

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Industry> IndustryList {get; set;}
}

public class Industry
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public double value {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int PortfolioId {get; set;}
}
```

Suppose I want to create a simple View that will allow a user to edit the properties of one portfolio.

On the view page, I want to create 2 text boxes and 2 drop down lists. Then the user would be able to select an industry from the drop down lists and then input some value in the associated text box. What I would want is the IndustryList for that Portfolio to contain the 2 Industry objects.

For instance:

- DropDownList1 has "Fast Food" selected. The textbox associated to
  that same object has a value of 2.5.
- DropDownList2 has "Fashion"
  selected. The textbox associated to that same object has a value of
  45.3.

The list for that Portfolio would have two Industry objects with the data from the example.

Is it possible to map two or more HTML objects (i.e. textboxes, dropdowns, etc) in a View to a single object in a collection like this?

Comment: Did you actually try anything? If I understand correctly your "problem", it should work without any problems... Return with a reproducible code when it doesn't work :) But "I'm new" is not a valid argument. It just means you have to try a bit harder and do a little research first.

Comment: I did in fact try a few different things. In this case, I have successfully implemented instances where I have a single HTML element that corresponds to a single property. For instance, when a checkbox corresponds to whether a boolean is true or false, I used something to the effect of: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Boolean).

Comment: Can you post your view code?

Comment: So the problem is...? Because the answer to your question is simple "yes".

Comment: Yes the answer is to the question is Yes but you not sure if you tried anything to make it work or not!